# I am mic'ing my amp and running it through Garageband, and it sounds really bad! Is it something to do with Garageband, or is my mic setup wrong?

Tags: recording, microphones, homerecording, garage-band

My set up is as follows : Fender Tele --> Zoom G3XN --> Blackstar ID Core 10 --> Behringer Dynamic Mic (1 inch away from speaker) --> Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 (Line Setting) --> Garageband.

The tone from my amp sounds good and completely to my liking. But the audio signal that is captured in Garageband sounds muffled and unclear. It requires a lot of EQ-ing in Garageband to get a half-decent tone.

I cannot understand why this is the case. Few reasons I can think of:
1) A 10 watt modeling amp is not really perfect for mic'ing up in the first place.
2) There is something wrong with the default Garageband setting when trying to record mic'ed amps.

Also, the cleaner tones record significantly better than over-driven tones.

If anyone has any experience with such a setup, please help!!

Comment: Have you tested the mic on voice? Also check the sound if you pull the mic back 30cm, then 60.. on axis & off axis.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have tested it on vocals. Sounds absolutely fine. Like I said, clean guitar and even acoustic guitar records well. Its just that when I dial in overdrive, the sound becomes muffled and raspy.

Comment: That's why i suggested the next tests. My first guess is that a cheap mic is just not handling the SPL well.

Comment: Yes, I'll try out what you're saying. My mic is indeed a rather not-expensive-at-all Behringer XM8500 dynamic mic. Just out of curiosity, is the distance of the mic from the speaker related to how much sound pressure it can handle?

Comment: Sound falls off logarithmically. at 2ft there is 'half' the level as at 1ft. [the 'half' depends on how you are measuring it, but will do as a rough guide for these purposes] Without test gear you won't be able to measure actually how loud the amp is, nor how that relates to the mic's maximum SPL, but changing the distance is a simple practical test. Additionally, changing the angle of incidence will test where the speaker is brightest.

Comment: @Tetsujin This worked like a charm. Placed the mic around 40 cm from the amp. Getting crystal clear clean and OD tones. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following comments, my initial suspicions seems to have been correct - the mic cannot handle the SPL.

Sound falls off logarithmically. at 2ft there is 'half' the level as at 1ft. [the 'half' depends on how you are measuring it, but will do as a rough guide for these purposes]
Without test gear you won't be able to measure actually how loud the amp is, nor how that relates to the mic's maximum SPL, but changing the distance is a simple practical test. Additionally, changing the angle of incidence will test where the speaker is brightest.

Moving it away a foot or two should clear up the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Don't plug a microphone into a Line input.  There's more to Mic and Line inputs than attenuation.

Maybe the mic just won't take that sort of level.  Turn the amp down or move the mic further away.

Look at the recorded waveform in Garageband.  Does it resemble the Before or After picture?  If the Before, you've got an audio signal 'hitting the buffers' somewhere!

[image]